# Getting Solr Admin user password as a system variable

Tags: solr, solrj

Is there default solr enviroment property that is available to get the solr admin user () and password (). so that i can use this property instead of hardcoding the admin user and password in my solr db-data-config.xml below. I know I could define a property that can solve this purpose but wanted to know if there is any property already available

below

```
<entity name="test" processor="SolrEntityProcessor" url="http://<adminuser>:<password>@<server>:<port>/solr/test_core/" query="*:*"
fl="*">
```

Answer (score 0):

DIH Request Parameters
Request parameters can be substituted in configuration with placeholder `${dataimporter.request.paramname}`, as in this example:
You can define the datasource as below.

```
<dataSource driver="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"
            url="${dataimporter.request.jdbcurl}"
        user="${dataimporter.request.jdbcuser}"
        password="${dataimporter.request.jdbcpassword}" />
```

These parameters can then be passed to the full-import command or defined in the  section in `solrconfig.xml`.

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/dih/dataimport?command=full-import&jdbcurl=jdbc:hsqldb:./example-DIH/hsqldb/ex&jdbcuser=sa&jdbcpassword=secret
```

Answer (score 0):

DIH can use jndi and encrypted password in order to connect to database.

```
<dataSource name="informixmydb"
   type="JdbcDataSource"
   jndiName="java:/comp/env/jdbc/mydb" />
```

According to the embeded jetty version, you will need to add two jars in jetty. For instance

- http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-plus/9.4.10.v20180503/jetty-plus-9.4.10.v20180503.jar
- http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-jndi/9.4.10.v20180503/jetty-jndi-9.4.10.v20180503.jar

You will need to configure jndi authentication in the /opt/solr/solr/server/etc/jetty.xml file

```
<!-- ======================================================== -->
<!--                      Configure JNDI                      -->
<!-- ======================================================== -->

<New id="informixDepluxDs" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
  <Arg></Arg> <!-- is Configure node id value -->
  <Arg>java:comp/env/jdbc/deplux2</Arg>
  <Arg>
    <New class="com.informix.jdbcx.IfxConnectionPoolDataSource">
      <Set name="User">solr</Set>
      <Set name="password">
        <Call class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.security.Password" name="deobfuscate">
          <Arg>OBF:*****</Arg>
        </Call>
      </Set>
      <Set name="ServerName">xxxxxx</Set>
      <Set name="IfxIFXHOST">xxxxxx</Set>
      <Set name="DatabaseName">mydb</Set>
      <Set name="PortNumber">15032</Set>
    </New>
  </Arg>
</New>
<New id="informixxxxxx" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
  <Arg></Arg>
  <Arg>java:comp/env/jdbc/mydb</Arg>
  <Arg>
    <New class="com.informix.jdbcx.IfxDataSource">
      <Set name="IfxIFXHOST">xxxxxx</Set>
      <Set name="ServerName">xxxxxx</Set>
      <Set name="User">solr</Set>
      <Set name="password">
        <Call class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.security.Password" name="deobfuscate">
          <Arg>OBF:*****</Arg>
        </Call>
      </Set>
      <Set name="DatabaseName">mydb</Set>
      <Set name="PortNumber">15032</Set>
      <Set name="DataSourceName">java:comp/env/jdbc/mydb</Set>
    </New>
  </Arg>
</New>
```

Password can be encrypted

java -cp ../lib/jetty-util-9.4.10.v20180503.jar org.eclipse.jetty.util.security.Password username password.

(https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-security-secure-passwords.html)

Regards

Dominique